# Do the VW T5 seats fit on the T6

Tags: vw, seat

Do the older T5 VW Kombi rear seats (benches) fit on the newer T6 Crewbus?

I want to know specifically about those "clip-on/removable" seats and NOT the sliding or swivelling seats of the Caravelle.

Comment: What years are these vehicles?

Comment: T5 = 2007 / T6 = ???

Comment: Are they seats that use the heavy wire loops in the floor to clip into? I'd bet that they do, and if you have access to both vans you could probably make a well informed guess by measuring – or ask on chat to see if anybody there has access and could measure for you.

Comment: @dlu What do you mean by "heavy wire loops"? My original T5 was stolen without the seats and I am wondering what I should look out for if I would buy a T6 or something similar so that I could reuse the same seats.

Comment: Ack, I'm confused. I think the T5 was part of the T2/T3/T4 (Microbus/Vanagon/Eurovan in the US) lineage. I'm thinking of the European floor mounts and the T5/T6 photos that I found look different. On the other hand given that they appear to be commercial vehicles, it might be possible to find accurate drawings of the floor layout for customizers that would give you the positions of the seat mounts. Found this which suggests that they will work: https://www.gumtree.com/p/campervan-caravan-parts/vw-transporter-t6-t5-rear-quick-release-kombi-1-1-1-seats-simora/1204892004

Comment: @dlu The seats on the link looks the same as what I have from the T5. I know the Caravelle model's seats are completely different but if I am not mistaken the Kombi seats should fit on the Crewbus?

Comment: The Caravelle is the one with the rotating "captain's chairs"? The stuff I've found calls the Crewbus a "Transporter Crewbus" – seems like your odds are good.

Comment: I have seen seats that can rotate and I have seen seats that slide forward/backward on rails. It is not those seats. I have the clip-on ones that looks like the picture on the gumtree-link, but I don't know what it is called.